# intermediate field $\mathbb{F_{p}} \subset \mathbb{F_{p^{n}}} \subset \overline{\mathbb{F_{p}}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have trouble solving the following problems:

Let $p$ be a prime number and $K$ a field with characteristic $p$. Let $\overline{K} \supset K$ be the algebraic closure of $K$.

i) Let $n>0$ be a natural number. Prove that the polynomial $f(X)=X^{p^{n}}-X$ has exactly $p^{n}$ different roots in $\overline{K}$.

ii) Now consider $K=\mathbb{F_{p}}$ embedded into the algebraic closure $\overline{ \mathbb{F_{p}}}\supset \mathbb{F_{p}}$. Define $\mathbb{F_{p^{n}}}:=\{x\in \overline{ \mathbb{F_{p}}}| x^{p^{n}}=x\}$. Show that $\mathbb{F_{p}} \subset \mathbb{F_{p^{n}}} \subset \overline{\mathbb{F_{p}}}$ is an intermediate field.

iii) Prove that $\mathbb{F_{p}}\subset \mathbb{F_{p^{n}}}$ is a normal field extension.

i) I know that I can write $X^{p^{n}}-X$ as $X(X^{p^{n-1}}-1)$ and then I have to find the remaining $p^{n-1}$ roots but I'm not sure how.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Clarification of used definitons:

The characteristic of a ring is the smallest number such that $1+...+1=0$.

Let $K,M$ be fields, the ring homomorphism $a:K \to M$ is called embedding.

Let $K\subset L$ be a field extension of the field $K$. An intermediate field is a field $M$ such that $K\subset M \subset L$ and $M$ is a subfiled of $L$.

Let $K$ be a field and $K \subset \overline{K}$ be the algebraic closure. The intermediate field $K \subset L \subset\overline{K}$ is called normal if the embedding $b: L \to \overline{K}$ satisfies $b(L) \subset L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i) The derivative of $X^{p^n}-X$ is $-1$, which is coprime to $X^{p^n}-X$. So $X^{p^n}-X$ has no repeated roots.

ii)  You need to prove that $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a field containing $\Bbb{F}_p$.  Since $x^p-x=0$ for all $x\in \Bbb{F}_p$, $\Bbb{F}_p\subseteq \Bbb{F}_{p^n}$.  To show that $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ is closed under addition, prove the identity $$(X+Y)^{p^n}=X^{p^n}+Y^{p^n}.$$  It is clear that $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ is closed under multiplication and taking inverses (of non-zero elements).

iii)  If an irreducible polynomial $p(X)\in\Bbb{F}_p[X]$ has a root in $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$, then $p(X)$ is not coprime to $X^{p^n}-X$, so $p(X)$ must divide $X^{p^n}-X$.  Therefore, all roots of $p(X)$ are in $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$, and this means $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a normal extension of $\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Thank you. Why is the derivative -1? And I think we proved that identity after introducing the Frobenius endomorphism in the lecture.

Comment: The derivative of $X^{p^n}-X$ is $p^nX^{p^n-1}-1$, but $p=0$ here.

Comment: Thanks. Why is $p=0$ all the sudden? It's supposed to be a prime number. Why are we considering the derivative to begin with?

Comment: Because your field has characteristic $p$, we have $p=0$ in this field.

Comment: About the derivative, read this [pdf](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/oldwebpages/Math581Fall2015/Repeated%20Roots.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, we didn't have the proposition from the pdf in the lecture yet.